# wrx file handling with Developer Studio

Tags: eclipse, progress-4gl, openedge

Is there a way to make Progress Developer Studio 3.7 (Eclipse) generate all the wrx files (from the ocx) and place them in for example the rcode folder?

Clarification:
I dont know even how to make one wrx file. Have heard this "They get automatically created as soon as you drop an OCX control onto an ABL frame". But if you have removed that file, can you create it anew without having to redrop the control? And how do you automatically place it in a certain folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrx files contain the properties of an ActiveX you set in the appbuilder.
If you loose the wrx, those properties revert back to default values. You should check-in the wrx files into your version control system together with the source .

To copy the wrx to the rcode directory I use robocopy.
suppose your sources are in a directory named src then you can copy them using

```
robocopy src rcode *.wrx /s
```

Comment: Thanks. Wonder if there is a way for the appbuilder to generate the wrx directly to rcode folder.

Comment: You can specifiy the location of the wrx file in the Appbuilder procedure properties. I think it's better to keep them with the source and copy when needed. You can delete the rcode directories and recompile, you can't recreate the wrx, it should be treated as the same a sources in regards to backup & version control

Answer (score 0):

The wrx-file is generated when compiling in the **AppBuilder**.

[See this entry in the Progress Knowledge base](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000036036?q=wrx%20eclipse&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1)

Comment: So no way to generate all the hundreds wrx files automatically? You must save one by one?

Comment: As far as I know. Perhaps somebody else has a better answer. It might be possible to make a os copy the wrx's or something like that. I'm unsure if they contain info about paths etc.

Comment: How do you make the AppBuilder save the wrx file in a different folder than the w file? (so you easily can only get the r and wrx files to clients).

Comment: You don't I'm afraid (at least not that I know). AppBuilder is not a build tool. And really, neither is Eclipse. Either you need some bat-files or similar that copies the wrx or perhaps a specialised tool for building your software. Check out https://code.google.com/p/pct/